# callback handler for server side datatables v 1.10

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am using datatables version 1.10.0 for search capability.

I want to know for server side processing how do i manipulate the response.
For example I have a json response that returns with the records to display and also a status.

My requirement is, if there is validation failure on the server side, I do not want to draw the table and instead, render error messages on screen. Otherwise draw the table.

Simple Example below:

```
 $('#result').dataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,

        "ajax": {
            "url": "search",
            "type": "POST",
            //"dataSrc": "resultList",
            "dataSrc": function ( json ) {
        if (json.responseStatus.value == 'Validation Failure') {
    //show error messages on screen
//prevent redraw
         } else {

    //draw the table with the  resultList
    }
              }
        "columns": [
                    { "data": "referenceNumber"},
                    { "data": "fileName" },
                    { "data": "documentType" },
                    { "data": "uploadType" },
                    { "data": "createdBy" },
                    { "data": "memberName" },
                    { "data": "dateOfBirthStr"},
                    { "data": "createdDateStr" },
                    { "data": "comment" },
                    { "data": "status" }
                ]
    } );
```

UPDATE:
On the server side I return 403:

return new ResponseEntity(searchUploadResponse, HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);

On the client side:

```
$('#result').dataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "search",
        "type": "POST",
        "dataSrc": "resultList",
                 error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                       //handle errorThrown in here
                     alert("error" + jqXHR  + " : " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
                 }
    } ,
```

The result is i can show my error messages.
datatables blocks access to the table with the "processing" div.

Answer (score 1):

I would return a different status code on the json file instead of a `200` `Success` status so the datatable doesn't load any data.

Then, I can catch the error code using [`.ajaxError()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxerror/) and do what I'd like to do when that error code appears.

For example, you can return a `503` code status then on the same page as datatabes, you can do something like this:

```
$("#result").ajaxError(function(event, jqxhr, request, settings){
   if(jqxhr.status == 503) alert("Validation Failure");    
});
```

So you can handle the event, since datatables will just blank out if it doesn't get a 200 status code response from the server.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want to have my conditions on a response status, not http status code. The reason been, my webapp needs to support IE8+. If i return a status code other than 200 the browser may overwrite my changes.

Comment: You can also get the response status text if that's what you're asking, this is all exposed in the `jqxhr` object. See here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

Comment: Also, if you'll be returning a `200` status, you will want to use `$.ajaxSuccess()` instead of `$.ajaxError()`, the usage is the same as the example in my response.  See here: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/

Comment: I can get the response status value. Its the logic inside the conditions I want resolved. i want to have control over when i allow datatables to redraw/refresh the table.

Comment: returning the correct http status code and using error callback is a valid solution. I was still hoping to handle it my way

Comment: If your script isn't returning any json then the datatable will not load data. If an unauthenticated user is trying to view the datatable, they should be prompted to authenticate or be redirected to authentication. Not sure what you're trying to accomplish here or I might be able to give a better suggestion

Comment: as i stated above, the response is json. I want to manipulate it on the client side based on a defined status. if that is not recommended or not possible then i will utilise http status codes and error callback.

Comment: if you look at the example above; if a certain status is returned in the json response, display error message and prevent redraw. if success then draw the table with the  resultList. i have updated my example above with the approach you recommended. i want to know all possible ways before implementing my changes. thanks

Comment: How is that different than what I said to do in the first place?

Comment: What is a user defined status?

Comment: How are you adding your own properties to the original json object that datatables requires for serverside processing in the first place?  Or is that what you're trying to do, because if you are, I strongly suggest otherwise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62386/discussion-between-shane-lee-and-zee-tee).